# How to omit a property from a partial<type> in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to allow a partial without allowing an id for a typescript method update that goes like:

```
update(id: number, newObject:Omit<Partial<Object>,id>): CustomObject {
  const index =  this.objects.findIndex(
    (object: CustomObject) => object.id == id
  );

this.objects[index] = {
  ...this.objects[index],
  ...newObject
};

return this.object[index];
```

}

This approach though seems to fail as I can still pass an object with the id.

Answer (score 1):

By separating the id field from a base class, you could simply use the base class as the contract, therefore omitting the id field. Of course you can extend that class with the id field where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I use a generic type like this:

```
export type PickPartial<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>
```

Used like so:

```
type MyType = PickPartial<{ hat: string, cat: string, dog: string }, "cat" | "dog">

const obj: MyType = { hat: "top hat" };
// compiles successfully

const obj2: MyType = { hat: "beanie", cat: "fluffy" };
// compiles successfully

const obj3: MyType = { hat: "cowboy hat", cat: "fluffy", dog: "buddy" };
// compiles successfully

const obj4: MyType = { cat: "fluffy", dog: "buddy" };
// error: 'hat' is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, in Typescript you can pass as an argument an object which has more properties than the type which is expected in the function itself.

For example - in this code there is no error:

```
type Employee = {
    name: string;
    salary: number;
}

function foo(person: Employee){
    console.log('hi')
}

const bigObj = {
    name: "f",
    salary: 1,
    add: 2
}

foo(bigObj)
```

Comment: Yeah, my question is how to allow for a partial, but forbid a property, in this case the "id"